# Simpler way to concatenate 3 or more lists in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, concatenation, simplify

The aim is to merge four lists `result`, `trainAcc`, `crossAcc` and `testAcc`, each of the same length column wise and store the resulting matrix as a CSV file along with necessary headings.

The following is my working code to do this.

```python
acc = np.concatenate((np.array(result,ndmin=2).T,
                    np.array(trainAcc, ndmin=2).T, 
                    np.array(crossAcc, ndmin=2).T,
                    np.array(testAcc, ndmin=2).T), axis=1)
acc = np.concatenate((np.array(["Classifier","Train Accuracy", "CV Accuracy", "Test Accuracy"], ndmin=2), acc), axis=0)

with open("bestClassifier.csv", 'wb') as f:
    csv.writer(f).writerows(acc)
```

As you can see, the code is not so aesthetically pleasing for a task so simple. All lists have to be converted to two dimensional arrays and transposed in order to be merged column-wise.

Is there a simpler way to do this task with or without NumPy?

Comment: Maybe using `pandas` would help with this?

Comment: @DainDwarf: Thanks for the suggestion. It would help even more if you post with a working example.

Comment: Seems you're looking for Python's zip function?

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge: `zip` function? This is the first time I hear of such a feature in Python. Could you expand on that?

Comment: I've edited my answer in the hope that you will use the `writerow()` method instead of concatenating arrays of different nature...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not

```
acc = np.array((result, trainAcc, crossAcc, testAcc)).T
```

testing it

```
In [14]: np.array(([1,2,3,4,5],[10,20,30,40,50])).T
Out[14]: 
array([[ 1, 10],
       [ 2, 20],
       [ 3, 30],
       [ 4, 40],
       [ 5, 50]])
```

What about the output?

```
In [25]: acc = np.array(([1,2,3,4,5],[10,20,30,40,50])).T

In [26]: with open('pip.csv','w') as f:
   ....:     writer = csv.writer(f)
   ....:     writer.writerow(['Units', 'Tens'])
   ....:     writer.writerows(acc)

In [27]: !cat pip.csv
Units,Tens
1,10
2,20
3,30
4,40
5,50
```

Comment: Wow! Simple and aesthetic. It is just the thing I was looking for!

Comment: Wonderful! You've addressed both my problems stated in the question: combining column lists and adding column headings for CSV storage.

Comment: Do you understand how does `np.array((result, trainAcc, crossAcc, testAcc))` work? [The docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.creation.html#arrays-creation) fortunately are very clear on this issue.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't pop up in my mind as I was working backwards from my problem, hence the needlessly complex code.

Answer (score 2):

To merge lists:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [10, 20, 30, 40]
c = [100, 200, 300, 400]

zipped = zip (a, b, c)

print (zipped)

# [(1, 10, 100), (2, 20, 200), (3, 30, 300), (4, 40 400)]
```

Comment: A succinct method indeed, and you also didn't have to use NumPy for the operation. It works well with `csv.writer` too. Too bad I could only accept one answer.